# Pandas DataFrame Groupby How to get the group as a list and get average of particular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

```
p    m    r
p1     m1   120
p1     m2   34
p1     m3   56
p2     m4   54
p2     m5   58
```

I need to group data on p and get the average of r and output should be like this:

```
p      m           r
p1    [m1,m2,m3]  70
p2    [m4,m5]     56
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and `agg`:

```
>>> df.groupby('p').agg({'m': [list], 'r': ['mean']}).droplevel(1, axis=1) 
               m   r
p                   
p1  [m1, m2, m3]  70
p2      [m4, m5]  56
```

Or,

```
>>> df.groupby('p').agg({'m': [list], 'r': ['mean']}).droplevel(1, axis=1).reset_index()
 
    p             m   r
0  p1  [m1, m2, m3]  70
1  p2      [m4, m5]  56
```

Or,

```
>>> df.groupby('p', as_index=False).agg(m=('m', list), r=('r','mean'))
    p             m   r
0  p1  [m1, m2, m3]  70
1  p2      [m4, m5]  56
```